# Ubuntu 14.014 not detecting my ASUS Zenfone 5

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, android, asus

I want to connect my ASUS Zenfone 5 to an Ubuntu OS but the system is not detecting it. I have tried to install mtpfs but still its not working.

Need help on this.

Thanks.

Comment: @CharlesGreen I don't seen anything to do with Ubuntu Touch here..

Comment: My bad - I read it to be that he was trying to install Ubuntu onto the phone.

Answer (score 2):

Try to plug it into on of your USB 3.0 ports (xhci_hcd) if you have one.

I have the same issue when I plug my zenfone into any of my USB 2.0 ports (ehci-pci), it just detects the phone but doesn't mount it.

Comment: I don't know why your answer was downvoted without comment, but IMHO it's a good answer.  (maybe it just didn't work in this particular case, but then the polite thing would have been to leave a comment) Don't be discouraged and keep up the good work! :-)

Comment: Maybe someone downvoted it becaue the hind didn't help? I don't know

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem with my Zenfone 6.

I found the answer here on the ubuntu forums:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226702

It's actually really simple: you just get the vendorId:productId from running `lsusb`, add those IDs to two files, restart the "udev" services, and finally reboot your computer. Follow the link above, it'll walk you through.

Comment: Please include the steps in your answer - if the link goes dead no-one will know what to do...